# Angular TypeError: _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.ɵɵdefineInjectable is not a function

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, lazy-loading

I am running my app [LiveCicle](https://livecicle.com) and when I navigate to the map route I get this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.ɵɵdefineInjectable is not a function
TypeError: _angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.ɵɵdefineInjectable is not a function
    at tm.service.ts:9
```

This is weird because I am defining tm service as a provider in the route's module.

```
@NgModule({
 providers: [
    {
      provide:
        HTTP_INTERCEPTORS
      ,

      useClass: AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    TicketMasterService
  ],
})
```

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'map',   loadChildren: () => import('./event-map-page/event-map-page.module').then(m => m.EventMapPageModule)},

  {path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full'},

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I only get this error in production. everything works perfectly when I run locally.

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { DataService } from '../../services/dataService/data.service';
import { TmEvent } from '../../models/tmEvent/tm-event.model';
@Injectable()
export class TicketMasterService {
  noAuthHeader = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'NoAuth': 'True'})};
  private readonly TM_EVENTS = 'TM_EVENTS';
  tmEvents: any = [];
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private data: DataService) {
  }

  fetchTmData() {
    this.http.get(environment.apiBaseUrl + '/ticketmaster-events', this.noAuthHeader).subscribe(res => {
      this.getTheFields(res);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste TicketMasterService?

Comment: @Nosheep pasted

Comment: remove providedIn: 'platform', because you're already have this service as a provider at a module level or do it vice versa.

Comment: @Nosheep still get the same error... also I noticed when you click on the route twice you get this error `core.js:4117 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'Éµmod' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Éµmod' of undefined
    at getNgModuleDef (core.js:1880)`

Comment: Try to remove Injectable() completely.

Comment: @Nosheep it wont compile `Either add the @Injectable() decorator to 'TicketMasterService', or configure a different provider (such as a provider with 'useFactory').`

Answer (score 2):

I experimented with a similar problem
go to `./node_modules/ng-inline-svg/lib_esmodule/svg-cache.service.js` and search for `ɵɵ` and delete it
or click on the error and search for `ɵɵ` and delete it
I hope this can be useful for anyone

Comment: This worked but how will i set it up on production

Answer (score 1):

@Jonathan which angular version are you using?

I experimented with a similar problem when I updated to angular 8.

Like you, my application worked fine locally but not in production. Lazy loading or double click events were not working fine and the application thrown a similar error.

After surfing on Internet, I found some solutions updating dependencies for angular core, cli.. but none of them solved the problem.

In my case, problem was in the production configuration files, specifically in tsconfig.e2e.json file. But also review your local configuration at tsconfig.json file.

Make sure you are using these parameters for angular 8 or later versions:

"module": "esnext",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"target": "es5"

I hope this can be useful for someone...